# Socket programming with heartbeat keeps falling out of sync

Tags: c#, sockets, design-patterns

I have a device I connect to via a com port and it has 3 functions:

- Heartbeat I must Acknowledge
- Status Check
- Start devices operation

When the device sends a heartbeat to me, my next message to the device must always be an acknowledgement or the device won't respond.

**The Problem** I have is that every now and again my application will send a `StartDevice` or `StatusCheck` command just after receiving a `Heartbeat` and it all falls apart

How do I solve this problem?

I've written a simple version of my code below:

```
public class MyDevice {

    ComPort comPort;
    Timer statusTimer;

    public MyDevice() {
        //Create a socket connection to the device
        comPort = new ComPort("COM5");
        comPort.Recieve += RecieveSomeData;
        comPort.Open();
        //Start an update timer every 5 mins
        statusTimer = new Timer();
        statusTimer.Tick += StatusTimerTick;
        statusTimer.Start(5);
    }

    public void StartDevice() {
        comPort.Send("Start Device Operation!");
    }

    protected void StatusTimerTick() {
        comPort.Send("What is your status?");
    }

    protected void RecieveSomeData(string data) {
        //if the device sends heart beat, send acknowledgment back
        if (data.StartsWith("Heartbeat")) {
            comPort.Send("Acknowledgement!");
        }
        //if the device is replying to status or 
        // a start operation then tell the consumer
        else {
            ReportStatus(data);
        }
    }

    private void ReportStatus(string data) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The protocol you describe is prone to a race. It can happen that the device sends a Heartbeat request at about the same time your application sends a StatusTimerTick. In this case the device will receive the StatusTimerTick before it will receive the response to the Heartbeat, even if this response was send immediately after the Heartbeat request was received by your application.

The only way to solve the problem is to redesign your protocol or the expectations. The easiest redesign would mean that a Heartbeat response must still follow each Heartbeat request but there might be some other messages received in between, like StatusTimerTick. If this is too complicated you might redesign the protocol so that your application will only send something whenever your device explicitly requests information but not by its own without such a request.

Comment: I don't have control over the device's protocol unfortunately, I've come across a few of these devices from several different manufacturers now that follow this pattern so I thought I would ask the question. Do you have any advice for how I proceed with that in mind?
e.g. Thread safe queues, Acks jump the queue, retry pattern?

Comment: @Smithy: no thread safety or whatever can fix this problem. The problem is in the protocol design, not in the application. Since the application does not know when a heartbeat messages will be send by the peer it cannot defer any messages until it got the heartbeat request and responded to it.